# How can I get the term frequencies of a document for multi-word phrases?

Tags: lucene

I am able to get the one-worded term-frequencies for documents in Lucene. How do I do the same thing, but for a custom list of multi-worded phrases? For example: say I have the following text in a document:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick onyx goblin jumps over the lazy dwarf.
```

The term frequency vectors would show:

```
Word       Frequency
----       ---------
the        4
quick      2
brown      1
onyx       1
fox        1
goblin     1
jumps      2
over       2
lazy       2
dog        1
dwarf      1
```

But what if I wanted to count instances of the phrase "the quick"? In which case, there would be 2 matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you are using simple Analysis chain. You can append [ShingleFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html) (with `minShingleSize=2` and `maxShingleSize=2`) to the list of token filters so the output from the token stream would look like:

`the quick` -> `quick brown` -> `brown fox` -> `fox jumps` -> `jumps over` -> `over the` -> `the lazy` -> `lazy dog`.

So you'll reduce your problem to the already solved problem.